# Can I replace a PLL Charge Pump with an Active LPF?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter

**Background**

I am using a [MAX9382 phase frequency detector](http://datasheets.maxim-ic.com/en/ds/MAX9382-MAX9383.pdf) in a project. The [application notes](http://www.maxim-ic.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/1130) recommend using a charge pump on the output of the IC. In PLL applications there is an up and down line that causes the voltage of the charge pump to go up or down. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_pump) says:

> The use of a charge pump naturally
>   adds a pole at the origin in the loop
>   transfer function of the PLL . . . The
>   additional pole at the origin is
>   desirable because when considering the
>   closed-loop transfer function of the
>   PLL, this pole at the origin
>   integrates the error signal and causes
>   the system to track the input with one
>   more order.

However, for my project I am not using the IC in a PLL, rather I will be using an ADC to measure an average voltage proportional to a phase and/or frequency difference.

**Question**

Do I need to use a charge pump similar to what would be used in a PLL? I was thinking I could just use an active low pass filter to produce the average(UP-DN). Am I forgetting about something?

**Some Details**

I will be feeding the PFD with signals that are in the 400-450MHz range and then will use an ADC to measure the average voltage at about a 1 Hz sampling rate.

In some circumstances I will be looking for a phase difference while in other cases I will be looking for a frequency differences.

Comment: What bandwidth does the phase detection need to happen at?  If this is for production use, try to use a different part than the unobtanium Maxim part.

Comment: @markrages added some detail to the question.

Comment: @markrages What makes you not like the Maxim part?

Comment: If you actually need frequency differences, I suggest you use a counter of some sort.  But this should work fine for deciding which frequency is higher.

Comment: MCH12140 is pin-compatible and actually in stock at Mouser.  If you just need phase detection you could use MC10EL07.

Comment: I'm not sure the Maxim part exists.  Maxim shows none in stock and unknown lead time.  Octopart shows zero stock everywhere.  There is more evidence for the existence of Bigfoot than the MAX9382.

Comment: @markrages from what I have found, PFDs have a higher resolution capable then frequency counters do for equal price. The problem with the XOR solution for phase only is that you can't tell negative versus positive phase differences. The MCH12140 does look nice though, thanks! I have the Maxim part sitting on my desk, they sent me a sample a few weeks ago. Wonder why none one stocks it.

Comment: from their ordering page: "Maxim is prioritizing manufacturer business ahead of non-franchised distribution. We are unable to dedicate any resources to support non-franchised distribution, and available inventory is reserved for manufacturer demand at this time. We apologize for the inconvenience."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely do not need a charge pump integrator for this application although you could use one if you wished.  The point of the charge pump is to integrate the output of the frequency/phase detector is a pulse oriented manor.  I don't think you need this level of complexity for what it sounds your trying to do so I wouldn't do it.

I also highly doubt you need an active filter.

If your only measuring at 1Hz then your averaging time is likely of a similar order.

That is you don't need "fast averaging".  This means your low pass filter can get away with a very low corner frequency, 10-100Hz maybe 1kHz max?

This is almost the exact opposite use case that the integrated charge pump is made for, which is converting the pulse train to a voltage to drive a VCO at as close to "full speed" as possible.

With a corner frequency as low you need, you can likely just use an LC filter and the rejection at the switching frequency of this device will be extremely high as it appears that the majority of the frequency content in the output will be between ~200Mhz and 6Ghz.

You may need an op amp or two after this filter to provide gain / fix impedance issues for your ADC but the high frequency content of the signal should be low enough that you don't need a very high bandwidth op amp for this.

One issue you do need to consider is the input impedance of the LC filter.  You'll need to take it into account when deciding how to treat the transmission line between the filter(s) and the IC.

EDIT: I have no idea how sensitive your ADC is to high frequency noise but to effectively filter the very high frequency content that will exist in the output of the frequency detector you need to pay attention to the high frequency performance of your filter as PCB and package parasitics are significant at these frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

In your application, if you aren't driving a VCO, then you don't need a charge pump or loop filter. The way your question is worded, it sounds like you're only using the phase detector.

That said, using an active filter as a loop filter has its own issues. Remember that your amplifier needs at least 100 times the bandwidth of the filter for its own stability, and that an op amp can put in a 90 degree phase shift all by itself.

Comment: But if there is no "loop" there are no stability problems.  @Kellenjb is just using the phase detector, not building a PLL.

Comment: @Mike DeSimone I had forgotten about how fast the pulses going into the filter would be. They probably will be too fast for the opamps I was looking at. I suppose I could have a passive LPF followed by an active filter with a higher order.

Comment: @markrages: I'm talking about the active filter's stability, not a PLL's. @Kellenjb: Whatever you try, make sure you simulate it.